# Load XML content onload Apache

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, cgi

Am trying for onload page content from backend(perl) using Ajax .When Tried with simple CGIHTTPServer then, the pages is getting load as required in particular Div's .

But as same page i moved to Apache Server , the content are not getting load .Am not getting any error also..:(

how to debug this error ....?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(onload)
function onload() {
$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
                 url: '/cgi-bin/onload.pl',
             async: false,
success: function(data) {
$('[key]',data).each(function(){
$('[name=chk_'+$(this).attr('key')+']').attr('checked',true)
})
}
})
}
</script>

<body>
<form>
<input name='chk_0' type='checkbox' />0<br />
<input name='chk_1' type='checkbox' />1<br />
<input name='chk_2' type='checkbox' />2<br />
<input name='chk_3' type='checkbox' />3<br />
<input name='chk_4' type='checkbox' />4<br />
<input name='chk_5' type='checkbox' />5<br />
<input name='chk_6' type='checkbox' />6<br />
<input name='chk_7' type='checkbox' />7<br />
<input name='chk_8' type='checkbox' />8<br />
<input name='chk_9' type='checkbox' />9<br />
<input name='chk_10' type='checkbox' />10<br />
<input name='chk_11' type='checkbox' />11<br />
<input name='chk_12' type='checkbox' />12<br />
<input name='chk_13' type='checkbox' />13<br />
<input name='chk_14' type='checkbox' />14<br />
<input name='chk_15' type='checkbox' />15<br />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: what does xml look like. Have you inspected the request in a browser console to see that it is being made and status is 200 and that data is returned?

Comment: Yeah I checked .Its working perfect in CGI server but not in Apache Server

Comment: if it's not working what is status of request in browser console?

Comment: Nothing ,just blank. NO error at all in browser console

Comment: I'm not asking about error... you need to inspect the actual request in network or net tab. There has to be something irregular

Comment: Sorry , I didnt get you ...:( nettab ....?

Comment: need to learn how to use chrome console `F12` or Firebug in Firefox